# What is a logical ground?

Tags: logic, metaphysics, contemporary-philosophy, grounding

I've been stumbling upon the expression and am now asking myself what it's meaning is. What does mentioning a logical ground refer to? Perhaps anyone could try to break down the possibly multilayered meaning of the term a bit. I assume that a logical ground is somehow related to explanation, but apart from that I'm not able say anything more about it. Providing introductory resources apart from the SEP article "Metaphysical Grounding" would be welcome as well.

Comment: Some example may help...

Comment: The "rational" reasons supporting an assertion.

Comment: At a more "technical" level, see: F.Correia, [Logical Grounds, (2014)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271001170_Logical_Grounds): "there
appears to be a threefold distinction between *metaphysical, conceptual* and *logical*
grounding. Thus, it may be said that the fact that the glass is fragile is metaphysically
grounded in some particular fact concerning its molecular structure, that the fact that the wall is red is conceptually grounded in the fact that it is scarlet, and that the fact that there are mountains is logically grounded in the fact that Mont Blanc is a ountain."